# Telegram бот на Python. Не вмещается текст(ДАННЫЕ С САЙТА) в строку в telegrame.. библиотека requests

Tags: python, telegram, requests

```
import config
import telebot
import requests as r


bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.token)
url = "https://wttr.in/Minsk"

weather_parameters = {
    "F": "",
    "1": "",
    "n": ""
}

request_headers = {
    "Accept_Language":"en"
}


@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def function(message):
    response = r.get(url, params=weather_parameters, headers=request_headers)
    print(response.text)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, response.text)

bot.infinity_polling()
```

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrFif.png -- телеграм

[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXsr2.png -- консоль(так как надо)

Comment: Вижу код, вижу несколько утверждений, и пару картинок, вопроса не вижу в упор.

Comment: Вопрос в упор: как мне сделать, чтобы погода показывалась в телеграмме так же как и в консоли.. Как я понимаю, в телеграмме не хватает места в строке, чтобы расместить всю информацию.. Поэтому я хочу сделать примерно так(но я не могу понять, как это сделать):

Morning
Инфа... инфааа... инфааа...

noon
Инфа... инфааа... инфааа...

Evening
Инфа... инфааа... инфааа...

Night
Инфа... инфааа... инфааа...                  то есть, чтобы всю все прогрузилось..

Comment: Надеюсь, понятно обьяснил..

Comment: Например использовать пре-форматированный блок, https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#formatting-options

Answer (score 0):

**Во-первых**, этот текст и не вместится в рамки сообщения (например используя телефон, всё равно будет неразбериха).

**Во-вторых**, насколько я знаю, можно сделать это с помощью `тройных кавычек`. Например:

```
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, """
Минск
       Wednesday 1 February
    -3
""")
```

Answer (score 0):

Тут ничего не сделаешь тут можно только поделить текст на несколько частей иначе никак вроде в каждом тексте не более 3000 символов